# Using numpy array with Org Babel

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I want to pass in 2 arrays and have python process them.   The babel block works when I put the arrays directly in but if I try to pass them in via headers, they don't appear as arrays to numpy.  My example follows for the failure is below.

```
#+NAME: p-list
[0.2757333815097, -0.0010721227154135, 0.0002933239156845]
#+NAME: q-list
[0.27571909, -0.00107294,  0.00029381]

#+begin_src python :var p=p-list :var q=q-list :results output listings :exports results
import sys
sys.path.append('./')
import numpy as np
import simple
#parr = np.array([0.2757333815097, -0.0010721227154135, 0.0002933239156845])
#qarr = np.array([0.27571909, -0.00107294,  0.00029381])
parr = np.array(p)
qarr = np.array(q)
print(simple.doit(parr,qarr))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
```

The doit function just calls numpy.dot()

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```python
#+NAME: p-list
#+begin_src python :results value
return [0.2757333815097, -0.0010721227154135, 0.0002933239156845]
#+end_src

#+NAME: q-list
#+begin_src python :results value
return [0.27571909, -0.00107294,  0.00029381]
#+end_src

#+begin_src python :var p=p-list() :var q=q-list() :results output listings :exports results
import sys
sys.path.append('./')
import numpy as np

#parr = np.array([0.2757333815097, -0.0010721227154135, 0.0002933239156845])
#qarr = np.array([0.27571909, -0.00107294,  0.00029381])
parr = np.array(p)
qarr = np.array(q)
print(np.dot(parr,qarr))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 0.07602619353732326
```

The variables `p` and `q` in the last source block are assigned the values obtained by evaluating the first two code blocks - note the parens.

What you are doing is passing *strings* to the last block. Consider this:

```python
#+name: foo
[3, 4, 5]

#+begin_src python :var x=foo :results output
print(x)
print(type(x))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: [3, 4, 5]
: 
: <class 'str'>                        <==== It's a string!
```

EDIT: To reply to the OP's question in a comment: Yes, it is possible to use the simpler string representation; you just need to convert the string to a list inside the Python program.

A way to do that is to use the Python `eval` function in the program to convert the string to a Python list. Here's a modification of the last example to illustrate:

```python
#+name: foo
[3, 4, 5]

#+begin_src python :var x=foo :results output
print(x)
print(type(x))
x = eval(x)
print(x)
print(type(x))
#+end_src


#+RESULTS:
: [3, 4, 5]
: 
: <class 'str'>
: [3, 4, 5]
: <class 'list'>
```

Afthe the `eval`, `x` is now a list, so you can convert it to a `numpy` array. Applying this idea to the original program gives:

```python
#+NAME: p-list-as-string
[0.2757333815097, -0.0010721227154135, 0.0002933239156845]

#+NAME: q-list-as-string
[0.27571909, -0.00107294,  0.00029381]

#+begin_src python :var p=p-list-as-string :var q=q-list-as-string :results output listings :exports results
  import sys
  sys.path.append('./')
  import numpy as np

  parr = np.array(eval(p))
  qarr = np.array(eval(q))
  print(np.dot(parr,qarr))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 0.07602619353732326
```

Comment: Your answer works.  Thanks.  Is there a way I can make the vectors appear in the document as normal text vectors.   Putting them inside python source blocks isn't how I expect the document to look.   Can this work with LaTeX verbatim also?  If not, I will still use your solution.

Comment: See edit for the first part. I don't know what you mean by 'Can this work with LaTeX verbatim also?` but it sounds like a different question, so you should probably create a new question for it.

Comment: Did you see the updated version? Does that work for you?

Comment: I will go back and try 'eval'.

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?